# Leap Motion (Python) - Bug or error in my code

Tags: python, leap-motion

Basically, I have the following:

```
if(controller.is_connected):
        print "Connected.."
    else:
        print "Not connected.."
```

If the device is connected, the output will be "Connected", however, if the device is not connected then there is no output at all. Is it something that I am doing, or, a problem with the API?

Comment: does the program terminate?

Comment: Is the line of code immediately before this statement executed? Perhaps your statement is only reached when the Leap Motion controller is connected.

Answer (score -2):

Try moving the else block's indentation over:

```
if(controller.is_connected):
    print "Connected.."
else:
    print "Not connected.."
```

Comment: Nope, nothing.. This is really weird!!